# Can't make button invisible from another activity

Tags: java, android

First, I click on **Go to level one** button in **MainActivity** to go to the **LevelOne** Activity from **MainActivity**, then I am going back to **MainActivity** and now here I need **Go to level one** button to be INVISIBLE.
I tried to accomplish this via SharedPreferences, but couldn't make it.
The code I posted below is working just fine, it just doesn't make my **Go to level one** button invisible when I go back to **MainActivity**.

I've done this so far:

MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bLevelOne:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, LevelOne.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            break;
        case R.id.bLevelTwo:

            break;
        case R.id.bLevelThree:

            break;
        case R.id.bLevelFour:

            break;
        case R.id.bLevelFive:

            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String result = data.getStringExtra("result");
                if (result == "milos") {
                    level1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

LevelOne.java:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bMenu:
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("result", "milos");
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.bNextLevel:

            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: onActivityResult can be called before onCreate

Comment: @pATKICAAAA What is your Activitiy's launch mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a problem over here.

```
 if (result == "milos") {
                level1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
```

it should rather be

```
 if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("milos") {
                level1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
```

Comment: Please do accept it as the `Answer` if your problem is resolved.